# UI.Layout jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm having a bit of a difficult time configuring the jquery UI.Layout plugin. It all seems straightforward when I read the docs but then ... things don't work.

I'm using current version of the plugin 1.3.0 I believe, and google cdn 1.5.1 of jquery. And 1.8.10 for jquery ui, if that matters.

Firstly I'm getting a popup when the page loads:

The layout-container "DIV/#content" has no height.
Therefore the layout is 0-height and hence 'invisible'!

That seems like a reasonable error message so I modified my css to give #content {height:100%;} and cleared the browser cache but no, problem is still there.

Second issue: although the resizer bar is actually present (I can see it in firebug, and interact with it as long as I know where it is at), it seems like there should be some matching css file with the library to style the resizer. The demos on the UI.Layout page however don't seem to have any css and they work fine! For example, all I want is something like this, http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/example.html, and when I do view source there's no style or no css included.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm able to resize, open/close, etc. so I feel like it's just a css issue...but like I said I can't find any 'default' css...does anyone know where I can find that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is REALLY poorly documented.. and I was beating my head against a wall, until I tried this....  you need to setup a CSS rule that explicitly states the vertical height of your "container".. or that annoying alert will spring forth.. and most likely your Southern Pane won't show up...  Hope this helps!

```
html, body, #myContainer { 
    width:  100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: I gave up on this a long time ago, but hopefully your answer will be useful to someone.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your apply, this did the trick for me and ended up my pain of trying to set this stuff up. Thanks!

Comment: In addition, with the latest layout manager, you also have to place the "position:absolute" rule.

Comment: Thank you so much @ericbae and alex gray.  Both have resolved a problem I have been having for hours now.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer won't work properly if your divs are initially empty. The following does the trick, without scrollbars showing up:

```
#myContainer {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I had to add `min-width: 1px; min-height: 1px;` to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the real reason.
https://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple:

```js
render : function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(options));
    return this;
}
```

That makes sense, and works perfectly if you never deal with subviews. But as soon as you need subviews—which in any real app seems to happen fairly early on—you’ll realize that jQuery’s .html() calls .empty() first, which unbinds all jQuery events on all child nodes. So the first time you render() everything works fine, but as soon as you call it again all of the events defined in this.events in your subviews will be unbound.